# Parse a Date of MMMM YYYY format

Tags: java, date, format

I have to parse a date string (e.g. "October 2015") to a Date.
So the question is: how can I parse a date of `MMMM yyyy` format? Its ok if the new Date object is the first month of the given month.

I tried:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("MMMM yyyy").toFormatter();
TemporalAccessor ta = formatter.parse(node.textValue());
Instant instant = LocalDate.from(ta).atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
Date d = Date.from(instant);
```

But it does not work since the day is missing.

Comment: @GaëlJ Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. Especially not when they are already using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, as in this question. It’s so much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = format.parse("October 2015");
System.out.println(date); // Prints Thu Oct 01 00:00:00 BST 2015
```

Comment: Note that this uses the System default time zone, which in this case happens to be "BST".

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. Especially not when they are already using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, as in this question. It’s so much better.

Answer (score 6):

What you have there is a [`YearMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html), not a [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) since the day is missing.

The following works:

```
String string = "October 2015";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.parse(string, formatter);
// Alternatively: YearMonth yearMonth = formatter.parse(string, YearMonth::from);

LocalDate date = yearMonth.atDay(1);

System.out.println(yearMonth); // prints "2015-10"
System.out.println(date);      // prints "2015-10-01"
```

If you then want that as a `java.util.Date`, you need to specify which time zone you mean, maybe UTC or system default?

```
// ZoneId zone = ZoneOffset.UTC;
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
Date javaUtilDate = Date.from(date.atStartOfDay(zone).toInstant());

System.out.println(javaUtilDate); // prints "Thu Oct 01 00:00:00 CEST 2015"
                                  // because i'm in Europe/Stockholm.
```

Answer (score 1):

For java 8

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("MMMM yyyy")
        .toFormatter(Locale.US);
    TemporalAccessor ta = formatter.parse("October 2015");
    YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from(ta);
    LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.of(ym.getYear(), ym.getMonthValue(),
        1, 0, 0, 0);
    Instant instant = Instant.from(dt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()));

    Date d = Date.from(instant);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat`'s `parse` method for that

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM yyyy"); //MMMM yyyy example: October 2015

public Date getDateFromString(String input) {
    return DATE_FORMAT.parse(input);
}
```

For more information, see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)

Explanation of format: 
`MMMM` indicates you are parsing full name months such as "October"
`yyyy` indicates you have 4-digit length years. If you wanted to parse for example, October 15, your format would look like this: "MMMM yy"

Comment: The old date-time classes bundled with Java such as SimpleTextFormat are notoriously troublesome, flawed in both design and implementation. Time to move on to the new java.time framework built into Java 8 and later. Sun, Oracle, and the author of this Question have.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a SimpleDateFormatter?
This works fine for me:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy");
Date d = formatter.parse("Oktober 2015");
```